# Building a grid algorithm with fixed width and height

Tags: algorithm, css, grid

I am trying to think of a way to make a grid of products that have aspect ration of 1:1.25(WxH) with screen fixed width and height of 1920:1080, I want to know how can I calculate the best width and height of each product that would be best use of space.

Ratio: 1:1.25 (ex. 300x375 400x500 etc..)

Screen size: 1920:1080 (W x H)

Products could be anywhere between 1-100

**For example I calculated these manually**

1 Product: 864w x 1080h each

2 Products: 864w x 1080h each

3 Products: 640w x 800h each

4 Products: 480w x 600h each

8 Products: 432w x 540h each

Anyone have any idea on how can calculate these without manually plugin and checking.

Comment: Isn't this [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem knapsack problem]

Answer (score 0):

There is O(n) answer (where n is the input) for this question and it is very simple

> max = 0
>
> for i = 0 to i = √n
>
> ```
>   i of them in each row and n/i of them in each column.
>
>   check the aspect if its height is greater than max then change max to its height.
> ```

when you find the maximum it is your best ratio.

Comment: I am not following how I can get the exact dimentions from the formula.